# SocketTimeoutException in client readLine() method on AWS

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-web-services, timeout, client

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that it works fine on a Windows machine, but it fails on Mac.

I created a basic Java Server code for socket connection. It runs on AWS Linux AMI, and I make a client connection from my computer. It works fine for first 4-5 answers from the client. However, after 4th or 5th answer, I don't get any response from the server and it just hangs. After a while, it gives SocketTimeout Exception.

I set socket timeout with setSoTimeout() in both side, and it didn't change anything. I wonder if it has anything to do with Amazon.

Client Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int portNumber = 9090;
    String connected = "1";
    System.out.println(WELCOME);

    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("ip", portNumber);
        socket.setSoTimeout(0);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out.println(connected);
        while (connected.equals("1")) {
            //read in situation
            String situation = readInSituation(socket, input).replace(DELIMETER, "\n");
            System.out.println(situation);

            //send option
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter option: ");
            out.println(in.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String readInSituation(Socket socket, BufferedReader input) throws Exception {
    while (!input.ready()) {
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
    return input.readLine();
}
```

Server Code is more complicated, but all it does is to respond to commands and print basic text on the screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `PrintWriter` over the network, as it swallows exceptions, most probably a prior 'connection reset'. Use `BufferedWriter`. NB The `ready()` loop is literally a waste of time.